# Titles & labels on ggplot double line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a title and change the axis names on a double line graph using ggplot. my r code...

```
aa1 = read.table("C:/pathway/data.txt", header=TRUE)
aa1$Year <- factor(aa1$Year)

aa2 <- ddply(aa1, c("Type", "Year"), summarise, length=mean(Percent))


ggplot(aa2, aes(x=Year, y=length, colour=Type, group=Type)) + geom_line() + geom_point(size=4) + ylim(0, max(aa2$length))
```

I have made several attempts at this, but can't seem to make any progress. Any help, including alternatives to using ggplot, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is a "double line graph"? A line graph with two series?

Comment: Is this not basic documentation stuff? http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Titles_(ggplot2)/

Answer (score 0):

You can add axis labels using `xlab()` and `ylab()`. You can add a title using `ggtitle()`

Try:

```
ggplot(aa2, aes(x=Year, y=length, colour=Type, group=Type)) + geom_line() + geom_point(size=4) + ylim(0, max(aa2$length)) + xlab("x-axis") + ylab("y-axis") + ggtitle("graph title")
```